# Setting \predisplaypenalty to allow pages to have displayed equations at the top

Tags: equations, amsmath

If you're okay with letting pages have displayed equations at the top, what's a good value less than 10000 to set `\predisplaypenalty` to? I mean a value that allows pages to have displayed equations at the top, but that tends not to allow "too many" such pages.

Also, will setting `\predisplaypenalty` to less than 10000 allow displays to be put at the top of a page if they're created with any of the standard LaTeX and `amsmath` equation environments (`equation`, `align`, etc.), or will some of them still never be put there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AMS and LaTeX alignments use `$$` internally so do use `\predisplaypenalty` and AMS  `\intertext` also explicitly sets this penalty before the restarted display after the text.

As for what value to use, it's a bit of a black art and somewhat dependent on your actual content. In the absence of any other suggestions I would use either `\@medpenalty` or `\@highpenalty`, the values set in the document class to be used for `\nopagebreak[2]` or `\nopagebreak[3]` with `\nopagebreak` or `\nopagebreak[4]` being the existing penalty of 10000.